# OpenID not accepted.OpenID authentication failed (Stratoslive login with google app account)

Tags: wso2, openid, wso2-stratos, wso2-identity-server

I cannot login on stratoslive using google app account.
The message is :
"OpenID not accepted.OpenID authentication failed".

I found this :
"https://wso2.org/jira/browse/STRATOS-993"

- Status : "Resolved"
- Resolution : "Won't fix"

Is it resolved or not ?
Why cannot I login on stratoslive with my google app account ? (xxx@gmail.com)

Thanks in advance

Max

Answer (score 0):

Status : "Resolved"
Resolution : "Won't fix"

This means the issue is resolved as it won't be fixed in future. Simply, the JIRA will not be fixed in future unless the JIRA is reopened again.

As the JIRA says what I understands is that you will not be able to use Google account to login to the Stratoslive account in future due to this error.

Comment: thanks for reply Maninda. But if I'm not able to use google account to login to stratoslive, why do they still expose this feature ?

Comment: Additionally I'm not finding an alternative way to login. Where can I register a free account ?

Comment: I can see a banner about "2-day window starting from Wednesday, January 30, 10.00 AM GMT" maintenance work. So probably the Signup button may be temporarily unavailable due to maintenance. Better to try after that time.

Comment: Note that "Get started now for free" button in the video in https://stratoslive.wso2.com/home/index.html is not available now. (The maintenance banner is shown at https://identity.stratoslive.wso2.com/samlsso)